# Disprove the statement "every positive integer is the sum of cubes of 8 non negative integers"

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Disprove the statement "every positive integer is the sum of cubes of 8 non negative integers"
May I know how can I disprove it.

As far as concern, 
0, 1, 2, 3... is can be obtained using the cubes of 8 non negative integers. 
eg. 0 = 0 x x 0 ....
8 = 2^3 x 0 x 0 x ...

Comment: Consider $23$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring's_problem

Comment: In fact, 23 and 239 are the only integers that actually requires as many as 9 cubes in their representation.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the interesting link =)

Answer (score 5):

Removing this from the unanswered list: this is an instance of [Waring's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem). In general, 9 cubes are required, rather than 8.